# User-Friendly Redirect If File Not Exist

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5

I feel like this is a rather common request, but I am too confused about .htaccess and couldn't find a solution by Google.

I have a Laravel instance in a subdirectory of the Apache2 htdocs. Now I would like to invisibly redirect all requests from the root domain to this folder (it should be the "root" website). But the tricky thing is, this is not the only folder, there are other folders directly in the htdocs, which should be reached normally. Just the "root" website is not in the root but also in a subfolder. For example:

- **https://domainA.com** should load **https://domainA.com/laravel/public** (including possible query string or parameters, *but invisibly for the user*)
- **https://domainA.com/websiteB** should be served as it is
- **https://domainA.com/websiteC** should be served as it is
- ...

I assume, part of this solution will be to list all the websiteB, websiteC directories in the .htaccess, would it be possible to automate this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't use Laravel but in your routing, how about in the / (which is the index) route function include the index.php  and die() at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a .htaccess in the folder you want to custom controle but you have to create some filter condition

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    ## RewriteBase /foo

    ## conditions to tell what to redirect ie on URI
    ## RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/a-folder/
    ## not websiteB or websiteC
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/websiteB/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/websiteC/
    ## if the file does not exist call index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ my/path/to/a/script.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

After you have to do something special in script.php for those HTTP calls

You can also rewrite the URI and pass it again to apache but things can be complicated after...